# I can not send applications to the phone from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions, android-4.2-jelly-bean

install a modified ROM to my razr i, from there I can not send applications to the phone, I get these errors eclipse

```
[2013-09-11 21:03:25 - MainActivity] Android Launch!
[2013-09-11 21:03:25 - MainActivity] adb is running normally.
[2013-09-11 21:03:25 - MainActivity] Performing com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-09-11 21:03:25 - MainActivity] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-09-11 21:03:33 - MainActivity] Uploading MainActivity.apk onto device 'TA32402UGY'
[2013-09-11 21:03:34 - MainActivity] Installing MainActivity.apk...
[2013-09-11 21:03:35 - MainActivity] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2013-09-11 21:03:35 - MainActivity] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-09-11 21:03:35 - MainActivity] Launch canceled!
```

logcat

```
09-11 21:03:06.577: W/PackageParser(10331):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
09-11 21:03:06.577: W/PackageParser(10331):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
09-11 21:03:06.577: W/PackageParser(10331):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:455)
09-11 21:03:06.577: W/PackageParser(10331):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:722)
09-11 21:03:06.577: W/PackageParser(10331):     at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:169)
09-11 21:03:06.577: W/PackageParser(10331):     at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:110)
09-11 21:03:06.577: W/PackageParser(10331):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
09-11 21:03:06.577: W/PackageParser(10331):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
09-11 21:03:06.577: W/DefContainer(10331): Failed to parse package
09-11 21:03:06.577: W/ActivityManager(409): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/MainActivity.apk
```

Comment: Clean and rebuild check if any setup installed on your device uninstall it and re run

Comment: ise it and I tried with another phone for a motorola defy and works well, with the motorola razr is that I want to run

Comment: Might not solve the actual problem. But, try from the command prompt using adb install -s. -s puts the app in the sd card.

Comment: I do not understand how to do it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913281/unable-to-install-apk/6087154

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the command prompt.

adb install -s "your_apk_filename".apk

Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639873/cannot-install-apk-on-android-device-through-eclipse/8646393#8646393)

Comment: and you change the permissions to the folder but no improvement

Comment: What happens when you try from the command prompt? using adb install -s?

Comment: happens can't find 'MainActivity.apk' to install

Comment: Copy the apk file from the applications bin folder in eclipse to a folder/drive. Move to that particular folder in the command prompt. Try adb install -s MainActivity.apk now.

Comment: 1772 KB/s (1082106 bytes in 0.596s)
        pkg: /sdcard/tmp/MainActivity.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]

Comment: That error message says there is not space or not sdcard. Can you remove the -s and try with adb install "Mainactivity.apk"

Comment: try without -s   1927 KB/s (1082106 bytes in 0.548s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/MainActivity.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]

Comment: OK. I just got this error message in one of the app. It was cos of the version numbers. Do you mind to post the logcat after the error message "No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/MainActivity.apk". Additionally, try to give a target device in manifest file. Is it just this app that fails to install or all other apps?

Comment: It happens with all applications sent from eclipse