# android: Installation Error:Unknown Failure-while running an apk file in

Tags: android, android-emulator

Yesterday I haven't got any error while using emulator but today I got this error check the image below. I have run as well as debugged many time but I am not getting the same error every time.

Error is popping up after installing the apk file. Please give the correct answer such that i can fix the emulator correctly and work on that

> [image]

Now when I compile I got new error check the below image while shows

> [image]

What I have to do ?

Comment: Have you tried to execute in real device ?

Comment: real device ha what it is

Comment: real device means in phone or tablet rather than emulator.

Comment: internal storageof the emulator is full I guess

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913281/unable-to-install-apk/6087154

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Reboot your computer. This has always worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue, I try this and works great.

```
adb.exe kill-server
adb.exe start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly remember, but try to reset preferences by option in Windows tab.
Or create a new emulator and try to run your program again. If above things won't work then enable debugging on your android device and connect your device and run it to see if error persist.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If running in eclipse, Please check the emulator settings..

This happens when AVD is already configured and a new andriod project is created.

So for this.. go to Run>> Run Congurations >> Target.. Select the AVD which is already configured and an option for choosing same AVD for future projects also.

This will start an emulator and thats it.. your application is up !!!

Answer (score 0):

If You Running In Eclipse, Check Your Settings.

Run Configurations - Common - Select File In Standard Input And Output - Click

Workspace And Choose Your Project.

And Just Click Run.

Comment: And what if you're running in your Adidas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the package name contains an uppercase letter,If uppercase letters are included, change them to lowercase.it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this issue. I used below steps for resolving the issue:

```
1]  adb uninstall your_app_package_name
2]  adb kill-server
3]  adb start-server
```

restart the emulator/device after executing above steps.

Now try to run the application. That must work for you.